# What does "the globe over" mean?

Tags: meaning, compound-adjectives

I read this sentence in a book review. I can understand the sentence but, I am confused by *the globe over*.

> Human history? Global economy? Her evidence for women *the globe over*
>   consists of thin, small facts cherry-picked to support outsize claims.

- What part of speech is "the global over" in the above sentence and what does it
  mean?
- How about  *cherry-picked*?

Comment: You should limit each question to only one phrase/question.

Comment: Consult [this] to see what you need to include in questions of this sort. But "the globe over" is tricky: it's a faintly pretentious way of saying "over the globe", which is itself a faintly pretentious way of saying "around the world".

Comment: "Outsize" is also a problem: one of those illiteracies that passes for normal (it should be "outsized" to be a real past participial adjective). Consider "Success for Downsized Workers?" (title of a PDF on the Net) and "Success for Downsize Workers?". Eventually, "cherry-picked" will turn into the faux adjective "cherrypick", as in "small, cherrypick facts that support outsize claims". _Few people are capable of expressing with equanimity opinions which differ from the prejudices of their social environment. Most people are incapable of forming such opinions._ Albert Einstein (1953)

Comment: Related: More about cherry-picking can be found [HERE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70550/cherry-picking-what-is-the-correct-usage)

Answer (score 3):

The phrase **the globe over** is merely an inversion of an adjectival prepositional phrase **over the globe** modifying *women*. The sense is **over the [entire] globe**.

**Cherry-pick** is a standard idiomatic verb phrase [meaning](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cherry-picked)

> to choose or take the best or most profitable of (a number of things), esp for one's own benefit or gain *cherry-pick the best routes*.

**Cherry-picked** is the past participle used as an adjective here.