# Cherry-picking -- from a bowl, a tree or a cake?

Tags: idioms, metaphors

I'm looking for information on the background of the cherry-picking metaphor -- cherry-picking as in: to select only the best of something. The image of 'picking cherries' is clear, but where are the cherries being picked from -- *a bowl, a tree, or a dessert* (including cake)?
So far what I've found is inconsistent. Etymonline doesn't have anything helpful, while Wikipedia and Wiktionary have different explanations.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking)

> The term is based on the perceived process of harvesting fruit, such
> as cherries. The picker would be expected to only select the ripest
> and healthiest fruits.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cherry-pick)

> Etymology A metaphor, from the idea of picking through a bowl of
> cherries and seeking the best for oneself, or the idea of picking off
> the cherries for oneself from a cake or dessert.

Finally, I need to put the correct word in (something like) the following sentence:

**If you are going to cherry-pick successfully, you've got to keep your sights on the whole _______.**

(the idea being that when picking the best from a selection, you still need to know about what you are not choosing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70551/202912

Answer (score 1):

You have your answer already, in your wiki quote. They are being picked from a tree.  The fruits ripen at different times so you have to select only those that are ready, leaving the rest to continue reaching maturity. Modern usage of selecting the best is derived from that.

'In certain varieties of cherry tree the fruits ripens at different time - rather like strawberries - and it's necessary to choose between the ripe red fruit which are ready to eat and the green/'not yet red enough' fruit which definitely are not. Hence the term "cherry picking" means to choose the best from those on offer/available.'..............Phrase.org.uk

Comment: I would not recommend Wiktionary, It is crowdsourced and not very rigorous.

Comment: He choice, not mine.  I cited Phrase.org.uk.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've upvoted though I'm still interested in more info. Could you add the link?

Comment: Why have you cherrypicked one of the two etymologies supplied by OP?