# Idioms for keeping the big picture in mind while picking out the details

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, metaphors

As above -- I'm looking for suitable phrases, metaphors or idioms -- standard or invented -- for *keeping the big picture in mind while picking out selected details*.

This is related to a [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538377/cherry-picking-from-a-bowl-a-tree-or-a-cake) of mine where I was trying to formulate an extended cherry-picking metaphor. But I'm not too happy with the outcome. It sounds very awkward. I'm hoping there are better idioms out there.
So far I've got:

> If you're going to cherry-pick, you've got to size up the whole tree
> first.

Or -- not quite so awkward but clearly a mixed metaphor.

> Cherry picking is all very well, but try not to lose sight of the big
> picture.

Any suggestions welcome

---

Edit: The original is a text in German where the writer wants to say: It's all well and good if you want to choose the functions of (say) a program that suit your needs but you should also know about the other functions. The metaphor works in German. (It's all very well to pick out the raisins, but you should still keep the whole cake in sight.)

Comment: If you want to choose the best, you need to know (about) the rest

Comment: Oh! Quite like that. Did you make it up or is it a standard phrase?

Comment: I just made it up.  In all modesty, I've always been quite good at that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use it. It sounds like it should be a proverb. Feel free to answer properly for upvote.

Comment: If you want a metaphor to be apt, then we need a real-life example. It would be possible to select ripe cherries even if you had tunnel vision and couldn't see the whole tree. P.S. Are you asking for a well-known phrase? Are we supposed to invent new ones? Does it have to be about cherries? EDIT, I see @Bruce Murray has forestalled me. Nevertheless please clarify in future questions - Thanks

Comment: Okay, but play around with it.  I just put what I thought worked in a hurry.  Knowing the best means knowing the rest. There's the best and then there's the rest. etc. endless possibilites

Comment: @Chasly. Edited.

Comment: @S Conroy - The raisins example is not current in English but it works perfectly well as a metaphor. I'm sure everyone would understand it.

Comment: @chasly. Thx. I might have overlooked this since I have an aversion to raisins.

Comment: In the German, the raisins are the best part of the cake. That is different the best cherries from among all the cherries.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat. Sure, but it's the closest English idiom I can find. The other thing is that some sources say it's picking cherries from the tree and other say it's picking cherries from the cake.

Answer (score 4):

At least in the US, you could say **don't** ***miss the forest for the trees***.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*miss the forest for the trees*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss%20the%20forest%20for%20the%20trees):

> *US*
> : to not understand or appreciate a larger situation, problem, etc., because one is considering only a few parts of it

In other words, don't focus so much on a detail that you lose track of the overall issue.

Comment: This is useful +1, although it doesn't 100% cover the cherry-picking idea.

Comment: @SConroy Cherry picking wasn't necessarily a criterion for the answer. It was just an example of a possible idiom—which wasn't liked. I answered based on the title of the question and the first paragraph. (After all, the original German metaphor seems to involved raisins and cakes …)

Comment: Yah... Perhps I should added that raisins in the German idiom are considered something like cherries in the cherry-picking idiom. For example you might like bits of a religion, but not the whole package and be accused of picking out the raisins.

Comment: By the way this idea helped: I'm considering 'cherry-picking is all very well, but don't forget to step back and admire the whole cherry tree.'

Answer (score 1):

How about **separate the wheat from the chaff**? From Lexico:

> **[separate (or sort) the wheat from the chaff](https://www.lexico.com/definition/separate_(or_sort)_the_wheat_from_the_chaff)**: Distinguish valuable people or things from worthless ones.

One could interpret this to mean "from the big picture -- wheat and chaff -- 'cherry-pick' what is valuable -- the wheat."